# Created genesis block and set up node. How to mine?

Tags: miner-configuration, altcoin-development

Everything seems to be going well creating my altcoin for fun. I forked the BlackCoin source on Ubuntu, successfully mined a genesis block, recompiled. I bought a droplet over on digitalocean running Ubuntu 12.04, compiled my *coind from source, and ran it.

I know that worked because my *coin-qt on my local computer had 0 connections before, now it has 1, and my *coind getconnectioncount on my droplet reports 1 connection.

Here is my problem, my client *coin-qt says there are 80000 blocks remaining. Of course, it is stuck on block 0.

How can I fix this and start mining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's predetermined that 80,000 blocks remain, it sounds like you haven't cleared out the checkpoints.

It's been awhile since I looked at anything other than Ripple or Nxt, but you should be able to find the checkpoints by simply searching for "checkpoint" in the code or the `assert()`s.

Also, to keep yourself from interfering with the original BlackCoin, you might want to use another port.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the checkpoints and assert functions. I already changed the port and rpc port for this coin. Following an online forum post, I simply commented out the original code and returned true on the checkpoint functions. Maybe that was bad advice, I will check again.